# get page title in styles.content.get

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am getting the content of a certain page and output it on another page in typoscript. what i would like to do is to get the page title and output it above the content.

This is my code for getting the page content:

```
lib.Section1 = CONTENT
lib.Section1 < styles.content.get
lib.Section1 {
        select.languageField=sys_language_uid
        select.where = colPos=0
        select.pidInList = 19
}
```

For printing the page title i'm thinking of something like this:

```
lib.Section1.wrap = <div class="title">{page_title}</div>|
```

but i haven't been able to find the right method. Googling didn't help as the most methods i found there involved an hmenu or tmenu, which is not very practical in my case because i only need the content of a particular page. Maybe there is someone who can help.

Comment: Which page title do you want to print? The one of the current page, or the one of the page from which you fetch the content?

Comment: The title of the page i fetch the content from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed use a [HMENU](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html), since other methods (using [CONTENT](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) or similar) will run into problems with translations and selecting the right page.

Here is a simple HMENU:

```
lib.pageTitle = HMENU
lib.pageTitle {
    special = list
    special.value = 19

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO {
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <h1>|</h1>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. I didn't know you can specify a page in an HMENU so that you get only one particular title. Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
lib.Section1.dataWrap = <div class="title">{page:title}</div>|
```

First of all i think you need to use **dataWrap** to insert global Values (variables). And after that you can access some global data like page title i think.

Comment: This fetches the page title of the current page, not the one from where the content is fetched. Is that what is needed?